# Texshop cannot open .tex file

Tags: texshop

I have updated TeXShop to 4.24, on mac majove 10.14. Not sure why now .tex file cannot open in TeXShop, even manually choose TexShop to open, there is not such option, it's in grey. Or even I drag .tex file into TexShop, only shows the file location. 
Typeset is still working, just cannot open once it's closed.

Comment: Do you have TeXShop set up to use an external editor?

Comment: Yes, I have sublime 3. It's working. But kind of slower.